# Element not visible -- XPath only finding style

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to find the following button with the XPath locator:

```
//button[contains(text(), 'Save Request')]
```

However, when I do this I am getting an error as:

```
Element is not Visible
```

When I try inputting this XPath using Chropath it seems to be highlighting on the "1" after the style XPath attribute. How would I get around this issue?

[image]

I have tried adding a wait until element is visible but still getting the same issue:

```
public CreatePartRequestModalPage saveRequest() {
    waitForElement(By.xpath(SAVE_REQUEST_XPATH), State.ELEMENT_IS_VISIBLE);
    saveRequest.click();
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreatePartRequestModalPage.class).get();
}
```

HTML as text:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ng-click="ctrl.saveRequest()" ng-if="ctrl.partsList.length > 0" style="" xpath="1">
                Save Request
</button>
```

Comment: Try to [wait for visibility of element](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: I have tried doing that and I am still getting the same error

Comment: You cannot get the same error if to apply ExplicitWait

Comment: Please see code above that I have added. I am still seeing same issue

Comment: can you add the HTML not just a pic...

Comment: I have added this above

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what the `0" style="" xpath="1">` is doing there it might have something to do with the problem

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use something else then `contains text()`

You can use `//button[@class="btn btn-primary ng-scope"]`

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried using this xpath too but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1):

To locate the button with text as **Save Request** you can use the following *xpath* based solution:

```
//button[@class='btn btn-primary ng-scope' and normalize-space()='Save Request']
```

But as the element is [Angular](https://angular.io/) element to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary ng-scope' and normalize-space()='Save Request']"))).click();
```

Comment: as you can see in the question he has tried to use `WebDriverWait` he costumed it to `waitForElement` I suppose... and I too think he should use different XPath... as my answer suggested...

Comment: @jamiemca Did you try out this answer?

Comment: See @jamiemca 's answer that it was actually a bug! I think he can't upvote yet... I think all the answers here are good... Here is my +1

Comment: @MosheSlavin I guessed it right :) that was the reason I have used _WebDriverWait_ to negate the _javascript_ effect.

Answer (score 1):

While other answers might be viable I would like to give another approach.
the problem is not finding the Element but interacting (clicking) with it before it is visible. A small workaround would be to `click` the Element via JavaScript.

```
// Assume driver is a valid WebDriver instance that
// has been properly instantiated elsewhere.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(SAVE_REQUEST_XPATH));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

That way it does not matter if the element is clickable by Selenium. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can also find element

1. By ID

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
   ```
2. By Name

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
   ```
3. By ClassName

   ```
   WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.className("button"));
   //or
   WebElement childElement = parentElement.findElement(By.id("submit"));
   ```
4. By TagName

   ```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
   ```
5. By XPath

So try to find element with above methods.

Try to get your button with class name, it will work.

Comment: I am sure you mean well but your answer is too broad and the examples are not relevant to the question...

Comment: i think every answer should have relevant explanation so i was just trying to provide different element finding methods

Answer (score 0):

Apologies all, it turns out there was a javascript error on the page and the button wasn't clicking. This is the reason why I was getting an "Element is not Visible" error. Thanks everybody for the help !

Comment: thanks for getting back to us! it is still odd that the error was `"Element is not Visible"`...